# Data overflowing into another column

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlalchlemy within my Discord bot to log conversations between staff members and our users.

Most of the time things get logged but recently started experiencing some issues inserting data into the table.

We're using sqlalchemy to insert into the database. I am no expert so probably created something incorrectly.

Here is the table object:

```py
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (db_user, db_pass, db_host, database), echo = True)
    meta = MetaData()

    logs = Table(
        'logs', meta,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
        Column('agent', VARCHAR(45), nullable=False), 
        Column('starttime', DATETIME, nullable=False),
        Column('endtime', DATETIME, nullable=False),
        Column('osid', VARCHAR(20), nullable=True),
        Column('nickname', VARCHAR(45), nullable=False),
        Column('discorduid', VARCHAR(30), nullable=False),
        Column('log', String(99999999999999999999999999999999999999), nullable=False),
        Column('tags', VARCHAR(45), nullable=True)
    )

    insert = logs.insert()
    insert = logs.insert().values(agent=agent, starttime=start, endtime=end, osid='', nickname=user, discorduid=uid, log=messages, tags=tags)
    connection = engine.connect()
    result = connection.execute(insert)
```

Here is the info about the table in the database:

```
MariaDB [discord]> describe logs;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| agent      | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| starttime  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| endtime    | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| osid       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nickname   | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| discorduid | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| log        | longtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tags       | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The error I receive appears to show that the column for the logs `log=messages` via `insert = logs.insert().values(agent=agent, starttime=start, endtime=end, osid='', nickname=user, discorduid=uid, log=messages, tags=tags)` is overflowing into my `tags` column per below with some data redacted:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'tags' at row 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO logs (agent, starttime, endtime, osid, nickname, discorduid, log, tags) VALUES (%(agent)s, %(starttime)s, %(endtime)s, %(osid)s, %(nickname)s, %(discorduid)s, %(log)s, %(tags)s)]
[parameters: {'agent': 'X', 'starttime': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 26, 19, 50, 55, 863000), 'endtime': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 26, 20, 39, 56, 392000), 'osid': '', 'nickname': 'X', 'discorduid': 'X', 'log': 'OffSec Ninja:\nHello X - this chat has been initiated by X so that we can better assist you.\n\nX:\nHi X how are yo ... (5500 characters truncated) ... com/attachments/847200149520515102/847212337203380234/somefile.PNG\n\n\X:\nthe last buffer is the one that I\'m changing from 5092 to 5098\n\n', 'tags': "last buffer is the one that I'm changing from 5092 to 5098"}]
```

The `tags` column gets populated when the support agent closes down the private 1 on 1 channel.

I checked the length of the `messages` data I am inserting and it came to be 5462.

Is this a limitation of mysql and potentially how much it can store in a row? or did I just screw up my table object?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the SQL is trying to insert *"last buffer is the one that I'm changing from 5092 to 5098"*, a 58-character string, into a `VARCHAR(45)`. It's too long.

I've never heard of MySQL letting text content overflow between columns. It just doesn't do that. So it must be that the Python variables `messages` and `tags` contain the text you see in the erro, *before* your code tries to insert them to the table. Debug the way those Python variables are set.

Comment: The data from my `logs` column is overflowing into the `tags` column. I don't want to increase the tags size since the data I *need* belongs in the `logs` column.

Comment: Why do you assume there is any kind of "overflowing"? The error message and the code you provided clearly indicates that the value you try to insert into `tags` column is too long (as pointed out in the answer). The question is: where do you assign the value to the `tags`? Is the error happening there?